# Handling JQuery ajax success object data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

Im having a hard time handling the ajax object pass back. Im trying to loop over each object and output each data value from each object.

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "sample.url",
  data: JSON.stringify(SDdata),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

  console.log(data)

    $('#SD_Title').html(data.PagedData[1].SD_Plan_Name);
    $.each(data, function() {
      $.each(data, function(index) {
        console.log(data.PagedData[index].SD_Plan_Name);
        $('#SD_Content').html(data.PagedData[index]);
      });
    });

  },
  failure: function(errMsg) {
      alert(errMsg);
  }
```

});

to console.logs keep throwing undefined??

The data im receiving

```
Array[3]
  0:Object
    SD_Plan_CreatedDate : "11/01/2016"
    SD_Plan_ID : 15
    SD_Plan_Name : "Jeff Harris D1 Replacement"
    SD_Plan_Status : 3
    SD_Plan_TotalCost : 75219.56
    SD_Plan_UnitCount : 268
  1:Object
  2:Object
```

EDIT 1:

```
Console.log(data) output

  Object
    PagedData:Array[3]
      0:Object
        SD_Plan_CreatedDate:"11/01/2016"
        SD_Plan_ID:15
        SD_Plan_Name:"Jeff Harris D1 Replacement"
        SD_Plan_Status:3 
        SD_Plan_TotalCost:75219.56
        SD_Plan_UnitCount:268
        __proto__:Object
      1:Object
      2:Object
      length:3
      __proto__:Array[0]
  Total:3
  __proto__:Object
```

Comment: maybe learn some basic debugging skills so you don't have to run to stack overfow everytime you're not sure about the structure of your data

Comment: `console.log(data)`

Comment: no kidding, i know how to debug lol

Comment: i think you should go for console.log(data.SD_Plan_Name); instead of console.log(data.PagedData[index].SD_Plan_Name);

Comment: @codenut throws undefined im trying to loop over the array and then the objects and output the SD_Plan_Name for each object

Comment: Start with the top level object and work your way down with `console.log` to see where it breaks.  In other words, verify all of your assumptions about the object. For example, is `data.PagedData` really an array? How many elements does it have? What is the value of `index`? If it is numeric, does the array actually contain that many elements, ie does `data.PagedData[index]` exist?

Comment: *verify all of your assumptions...*  ... because obviously one or more of the variables does not contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the issue using a simple for loop:

```
for( var i = 0; i < data.PagedData.length; i++){
  console.log(data.PagedData[i].SD_Plan_Name);
}
```

Comment: Try the `$.each(data.PagedData, ...)` example @dave 's answer. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need nested `$.each()` loops. You're getting yourself too deep in the data structure. I also don't understand why you're using the index rather than giving the callback function the second value parameter. Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "sample.url",
  data: JSON.stringify(SDdata),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

  $('#SD_Title').html(data.PagedData[1].SD_Plan_Name);
    console.log(data.PagedData); // make sure you've got good data
    $.each(data.PagedData, function(index, value) {
      console.log(value); // look at the value of a single item in the array
      console.log(value.SD_Plan_Name); // If the data structure is correct this should be the value you're looking for
      $('#SD_Content').html(value);
    });
},
failure: function(errMsg) {
  alert(errMsg);
}
```

Comment: This is throwing back undefined:

Object {Total: 3, PagedData: Array[3]}
3
undefined
[Object, Object, Object]
undefined

Comment: Ok, loos like you've edited your original post appropriately. I'll make some edits to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

as you say you data is :

```
  Object
    PagedData:Array[3]
      0:Object
        SD_Plan_CreatedDate:"11/01/2016"
        SD_Plan_ID:15
        SD_Plan_Name:"Jeff Harris D1 Replacement"
        SD_Plan_Status:3 
        SD_Plan_TotalCost:75219.56
        SD_Plan_UnitCount:268
        __proto__:Object
      1:Object
      2:Object
      length:3
      __proto__:Array[0]
  Total:3
  __proto__:Object
```

so try

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "sample.url",
  data: JSON.stringify(SDdata),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

    $.each(data.PagedData, function(index, value) {

      $.each(value, function(index1 , value1) {
        console.log(value1);// each value wll be printed like "11/01/2016" then 15 and so on
     });

   });

  },
  failure: function(errMsg) {
      alert(errMsg);
  }
});
```

Comment: Returns Undefined

Comment: could you please update your question with result of success: function(data) { console.log(data); } it will be helpful in finding the problem